# highlight the searched text using AngularJS when split by html tags

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to highlight the searched text on the webpage. I am getting the contents to the webpage from the server in the form of json response. In the JSON response. I am getting both html response with tags and also the non-html response. 
In my html response. there are lot of span tags which are splitting the the single word with empty span tags. Eg: "Searchtext" is in the form "`<span class="c1">Sea</span>rch<span class="c2">text</span>`". The words splitting is happening at various positions in the received word response.

I am using angular-highlight. "**angular-highlight**" is highlighting the word which is not split by html tags. If the words are split it's not highlighting. We have customized the code of angular-highlight. But, still it's not working.

`<span>Sample</span>` - will be highlighted

`<span>Sa<span>mp</span>le</span>` - will not be highlighted

`<span>Sa<span></span>mple<span></span></span>` - will not be highlighted

I also have used **trustAsHtml** method also. But, it's not working.

Please, can anyone come up with the solution.

Thanks in advance.

I have explained the scenario. I have modified the below code for highlighting the contents we are getting from HTML response. I have pasted the code for you reference. Please, help me in resolving the issue.

```
angular.module('angular-highlight', []).directive('highlight', function() {
var matchCount = 0;
var newCheckKeyword = '';
var component = function(scope, element, attrs) {

    if (!attrs.highlightClass) {
                    attrs.highlightClass = 'angular-highlight';
    }
    var count = 0;
    var replacer = function(match, item) {
                    count++;
                    var temp = matchCount+count;
                    return '<span class="'+attrs.highlightClass+'" id="highlightId'+temp+'">'+match+'</span>';
    }


    var tokenize = function(keywords) {
                    keywords = keywords.replace(new RegExp('^ | $','g'), '');
                    return keywords;
    }

    scope.$watch('keywords', function(newKeyword, oldKeyword) {
                    if(newCheckKeyword == '' || newCheckKeyword != newKeyword){
                                    newCheckKeyword = newKeyword;
                                    matchCount = 0;
                                    count = 0;
                                    scope.sendCount({count: matchCount});
                    }
                    //console.log("scope.keywords",scope.keywords);
                    if (!scope.keywords || scope.keywords == '') {
                                    element.html(scope.highlight);
                                    return false;
                    }

                    var tokenized    = tokenize(scope.keywords);
                    // Modified to skip HTML tags
              var regex = new RegExp(tokenized+'(?!([^<]+)?>)', 'gmi');

                    // Find the words
                    var html = scope.highlight.replace(regex, replacer);

                    //var htmlCount = scope.highlight.match(regex, replacer);

                    element.html(html);
                    matchCount = matchCount+count;
                    scope.sendCount({count: matchCount});
                    count = 0;
    });

}
return {
    link: component,
    replace: false,
    scope:{
          highlight:'=',
          keywords:'=',
          sendCount:'&'                                                
    }
};
});
```

Comment: make a working plunker with the issue or at least post your code

Comment: Show your code..

Comment: <span class="c1">Sea</span>rch<span class="c2">text</span> is generating by highlight directive or you are getting from back-end?

Comment: Yes, getting data from backend. The html data is dynamically generated and it is coming in the JSON format.